# MongoDB Failed: can't create ActualPath object from path dump: stat dump: no such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, database-restore, mongorestore, database

I have a bunch of mongo databases that I need to restore. I used `mongodump` to get the backup directories, which include the collections inside of them. Something like this:

```
|- mydir
|-- db1
|--- collection1
|--- collections2
|-- db2
|--- collection1
|--- collections2
```

I `cd` into `mydir` and do `mongorestore` and I get the following error:

```
2016-07-25T10:41:12.378-0400    using default 'dump' directory
2016-07-25T10:41:12.378-0400    Failed: can't create ActualPath object from path dump: stat dump: no such file or directory
```

Then I try to restore a specific database like this: `mongorestore db2` and get the following errors:

```
2016-07-25T10:47:04.413-0400    building a list of dbs and collections to restore from db2 dir
2016-07-25T10:47:04.413-0400    don't know what to do with file "db2/collection1.bson", skipping...
2016-07-25T10:47:04.413-0400    don't know what to do with file "db2/collection1.metadata.json", skipping..."db2/collection2.bson", skipping...
2016-07-25T10:47:04.413-0400    don't know what to do with file "db2/collection2.metadata.json", skipping...
2016-07-25T10:47:04.414-0400    done
```

No matter what I do or what I try, I alternate between these two errors. And it's the same for any of the databases I use.

I tried using the `--db` flag, the `-d` parameter, setting the dump path as the third argument (`mongorestore --db [db] [dump_path]`). Everything I found around Stackoverflow. Nothing.

I'm stuck on this and I have no idea how to proceed.

---

**EDIT**

OS: **Ubuntu 14.04**

Installed MongoDB following this guide:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mongorestore` with no dump_path positional argument is expecting there to be a folder named `dump` in your current working directory. If the folder `dump` does not exist, you will get the "can't create ActualPath..." error.

So basically if you do not have a folder named dump, you will need to pass that positional argument. So from the parent directory of `mydir` run:

```
mongorestore mydir
```

If you want to use the `--db` option you will need to specify the dump path all the way down to the directory that contains the .bson files for that database **or** a specific .bson file.

So for example to restore all collections for `db1`:

```
mongorestore --db db1 ./db1
```

Or to just restore `collection1`:

```
mongorestore --db db1 ./db1/collection1.bson
```

Comment: Sure, np. Would you mind also accepting the answer please. Thanks.

Comment: Is the dump directory still used even when output of mongodump is piped to mongorestore?